# Generating other classes beside the core ones

Tags: magento2, code-generation

As described in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html some classes are autogenerated on request (or at di:compile) based on some rules.
For example if a class that ends with `Factory` does not exist it is generated with a predefined content. Same goes for `Proxy` and maybe others.
My question is:

**How / if I can do this for my own custom rules.

For example if a class name ends with `Something` and it does not exist, then it should be generated in the `generated/code` folder?**

Comment: I've been exploring the evolution of this feature over the years and was curious if there's now an option to inject generatedEntities from a module. Despite delving deep into Magento and meticulously setting breakpoints, I've yet to discover a suitable hook to seamlessly integrate it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @WillemPoortman. The only think I could come up with based on the accepted answer below can be found here: https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/umc-crud/blob/master/etc/crud/di.xml. This is how the generators are "hooked" into the system. And the actual generators can be found here. https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/umc-crud/tree/master/Generator.

Comment: I faithfully followed the module's instructions and was thrilled to see my custom generator in `generatedEntities`. However, my excitement waned when I discovered an old `/app/etc/foo/di.xml file` lingering. This was initially created to test if Magento would recognize it. Unfortunately, injecting a generator from within a module doesn't work for classes needing runtime generation, such as a block argument with a 'Foo'-suffixed xsi typed object. Magento can't locate my Foo entity generator. Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: As I've done this a few years ago and my memory is not what it used to be, I don't remember exactly what, how and why I did, but I assume that the reason for creating another di.xml file at the root level was because I didn't find a way to register it from inside a module. I think the code generators come into play early on, before any module configuration is loaded. if this is true, then the answer is simple... you cannot do it from inside a module. I will try to dig today into the code again and see if I can find something that confirms this.

Comment: I think I got something.... So flow goes like this: pub/index.php which calls `Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);` which calls `self::createObjectManagerFactory($rootDir, $initParams);` where the object manager is configured and where the entity generator is instantiated,  and then returns an instance of Boostrap. But when creating an instalnce of bootstrap the object manager is instantiated and you cannot pass anymore parameters to the entity generator. This is done way before the modules are read

Comment: Correct, thanks for confirming the same findings. I think we can close this having to accept this simply can not be done from inside a module. I'm now thinking about moving a `di.xml` into the `app/etc/{custom}` directory during module installation if the file doesnt exist. Time for some prototyping now we got the facts straight. Thanks for your time, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a complete lack of documentation on creating custom generators, but its a slight abstract of the Zend code generator. Which you will probs have a better time find documentation for. But in terms of registering a new generator in Magento it's basically 2 steps to do so.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.code.generator.examples.html

### Create the generator

Generators are extended from the `Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\EntityAbstract` class and require the following methods are defined `_getDefaultConstructorDefinition` `_getClassMethods`.

Good examples imo to work from are either the factory or proxy generators.
`\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Factory`
`\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Proxy`

But a basic generator would look something along the lines of

```
app/code/Bigeyedeers/Generator/Code/Generator/Example.php
```

```php
<?php

namespace Bigeyedeers\Generated\Code\Generator;

class Example extends \Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\EntityAbstract
{
    const ENTITY_TYPE = 'example';

    protected function _getDefaultConstructorDefinition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => '__construct',
            'parameters' => [
                ['name' => 'objectManager', 'type' => '\\' . \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface::class],
                ['name' => 'instanceName', 'defaultValue' => $this->getSourceClassName()],
            ],
            'body' => "\$this->_objectManager = \$objectManager;\n\$this->_instanceName = \$instanceName;",
            'docblock' => [
                'shortDescription' => ucfirst(static::ENTITY_TYPE) . ' constructor',
                'tags' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'param',
                        'description' => '\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager',
                    ],
                    ['name' => 'param', 'description' => 'string $instanceName'],
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }

    protected function _getClassMethods()
    {
        $construct = $this->_getDefaultConstructorDefinition();

        // public function create(array $data = array())
        $create = [
            'name' => 'create',
            'parameters' => [['name' => 'data', 'type' => 'array', 'defaultValue' => []]],
            'body' => 'return $this->_objectManager->create($this->_instanceName, $data);',
            'docblock' => [
                'shortDescription' => 'Create class instance with specified parameters',
                'tags' => [
                    ['name' => 'param', 'description' => 'array $data'],
                    [
                        'name' => 'return',
                        'description' => $this->getSourceClassName()
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return [$construct, $create];
    }
}
```

### Update the generated entities array

I was having trouble adding a new item node into the type declaration from a module. Im sure with more time you'd be able to work it out.

But within `app/etc/di.xml` add a new item node to the `generatedEntities` argument of the `Magento\Framework\Code\Generator` type declartion that points to your new generator class.

```
app/etc/di.xml
```

```xml
...
<type name="Magento\Framework\Code\Generator">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="generatedEntities" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="example" xsi:type="string">\Bigeyedeers\Generated\Code\Generator\Example</item>
...
```

### Usage

Now you can inject your generated class just like proxies/factories etc. When you compile then it should pull your new generated class

```php
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryExample $categoryExample)
{
    $this->_categoryExample = $categoryExample;
}
```

**Edit by OP**
In order not to change the core file `app/etc/di.xml`, the configuration can be added in `app/etc/additional/di.xml` (or any other subfolder of `app/etc/`) and it will be picked up by the config loader automatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Code\Generator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="generatedEntities" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="example" xsi:type="string">\Bigeyedeers\Generated\Code\Generator</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: this works nicely if I declare my generator in `app/etc/di.xml`, but editing core code is not a valid option. Can I make it work somehow with all the code in my custom module?

Comment: never mind. I found it. I can simply add my own `di.xml` in a subfolder in `app/etc` and it will be picked up by the config reader. For example. `app/etc/additional/di.xml`. Thanks.